# Summing elements of matrix from a file

Tags: c, matrix

I have a `1000x24` matrix in a text file and i want to sum the adjoining columns of the whole matrix e.g. `col1+col2`, `col2+col3`, `col3+col4`,... `col23+col24` and store these values in a separate text file.

My code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float a[100][24];

    FILE *fp=fopen("D:\1980.txt","r"); //missing one \ here, should be \\
    FILE *fp1=fopen("D:\\sum.txt","w");

    for (i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 23; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]= a[i][j] + a[i][j+1];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= 23; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp1,"%.2f\t",a[i][j]);
            fprintf(fp1,"\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    getch();           
}
```

For example if a matrix in file `1980.txt` is like `[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]`, the output in `sum.txt` should be `[3 5;9 11; 15 17]`.

However, the code is not working and i am getting only a blank file. Please help on this matter.

Comment: Indent your code please.

Comment: i cant see where you have read the file values into the matrix `a[][]`

Comment: I think this 'FILE *fp=fopen("D:\1980.txt","r");' should be this 'FILE *fp=fopen("D:\\1980.txt","r");', you are missing the \\

Comment: `a[i][j+1];` maybe j+1 == 24 and `i<=999` --> `i<=99` or `float a[1000][24];` , `i<=99`  --> `i<=999`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you did not specify the size of the array correctly.I am assuming it is 1000X24.The second mistake which you did is you are not taking input from the file.The third mistake is in printing on line 20.You have to print "\n" after the first for loop.Here is you working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,j;
float a[1000][24];
FILE *fp=fopen("1980.txt","r");
FILE *fp1=fopen("sum.txt","w");
for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<24;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%f",&a[i][j]);
        //a[i][j]= a[i][j]+a[i][j+1];
    }
}
for(i=0;i<1000;++i)
   for(j=1;j<24;++j)
       a[i][j-1]+=a[i][j];

for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
    for(j=0;j<23;j++)
        fprintf(fp1,"%f\t",a[i][j]);
    fprintf(fp1,"\n"); 
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);          
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aadil. The code is now running as it should be. Thanks for your help. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good deal wrong with this code. I've formatted your main function and added in comments to point out errors:

```
int i,j;
float a[100][24];                   // This is only a 100x24 matrix your question asks for 1000x24 and you try to read 1000 below as mentioned by BLUEPIXY. float a[1000][24];
FILE *fp=fopen("D:\1980.txt","r");  // You are not escaping the '\' as mentioned by UniCell. FILE* fp = fopen("D:||1980.txt", "r");
FILE *fp1=fopen("D:\\sum.txt","w");
for (i=0;i<=99;i++)                 // Again only initializing a 100x24 matrix as mentioned by BLUEPIXY, but you should also check that you haven't read past the end of the file. for(i = 0; i < 999 && fgetc(fp) != EOF; i++)
{
    // As mentioned by haris you never read from the file. I have included some commented code inline to help with that.
    // int total = 0;
    // int size = 0;
    // local[25];

    // while(total < 25){
    //     if(fscanf(fp,"%f",local + size)){
    //         size++;
    //         total++;
    //     }
    //     else{
    //         if(size > 1){
    for (j=0;j<=23;j++)             // This will need to be switched to use total and size. for(j = total - size;j < total;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]= a[i][j]+a[i][j+1]; // This will need to be switched to use local. a[i][j] = local[j] + local[j + 1];
    }
    //         }
    //         else if(size == 1){
    //             a[i][total] = FLT_MIN;
    //         }
    //         if(fgetc(fp) != ';'){
    //             break;
    //         }
    //         else{
    //             size = 0;
    //         }
    //     }
    // }
}
for(i=0;i<=999;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=23;j++)
    {
        fprintf(fp1,"%.2f\t",a[i][j]);
        fprintf(fp1,"\n");
    }
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
```

Comment: Hey, Jonathan thanks for your comments. Yes you are totally right in your argument. I can identify my mistakes now and get the code running. Thanks so much.

Comment: @krishcal23 If this solves your problems I'd encourage you to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark. You may also consider going back to accept answers on your other questions if there have been some that solve your problems.